# How can I run tests locally with Xamarin Android?

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin

All I can read about unit testing on a Xamarin Android project is about tests run on devices. But what I am looking for are business logic tests I can run pretty close to my IDE (Xamarin Studio/Visual Studio), meaning *in* my IDE.

Isn't there a way to do it?

Comment: Can you specify what kind of tests you want to tun? I can think of classic unit tests or ui tests.

Classic method testing unit tests can be done inside your IDE while UI tests needs to be performed on a device (either a real one or the emulator or on Xamarin Test Cloud). Both test methodes can be done with nunit.

Comment: @tequilaslammer. Sorry. I mean business logic tests. So no, no UI tests. How can I do them in Xamarin Studio without using a device?

Answer (score 0):

If you have business logic that you can test which would not require you to run in the context of an Android device/emulator, you can use a more typical unit testing scenario. Create a C# library project and add your favorite unit testing library to it. Xamarin Studio currently supports NUnit if you want to use the test runner built into the IDE.

There is a blog post [here](http://blog.falafel.com/hold-right-learning-xamarin-unit-tests/) that should help. There is a more generic NUnit tutorial on [this](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/07/27/getting-started-with-net-unit-testing-using-nunit.aspx) blog post.

Comment: Ok I already did that for the core of my solution. Can I somehow do the same thing (running from IDE) for my android project?

Comment: No. You can't directly reference an Android app project. Instead, you should isolate your business logic into a separate assembly so that you can unit test it easier. You might want to take a look at this too: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/part_5_-_practical_code_sharing_strategies/

Answer (score 0):

Open your solution and right click to choose Add > Add new Project. On the now open window click on .NET beneath the Others section. There you see NUnit library project.

This works for method testing. Unfortunately you can not test your Android project that way as far as I know.